# Inconsistent number of document snapshots are returned from firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason the code below inconsistently returns data from firebase, there's a total of 3 documents in my firestore collection but whenever I access this route, it returns either three, two, or one document snapshot.

```
router.get('/outlets', (req, res) => {
    let results = []
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('outlets')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let result = doc.data()
          result.id = doc.id

          results.push(result)
        })

        res.send(results)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        logger.getLogger('API/OUTLET').error(err.message)
        res.send([])
      })
  })
```

Comment: Is this code executed on your own Node.js instance? If yes, have you followed the following instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?

Comment: Without understanding exactly what your source data is and what the code actually generates, there's not much we can do to help.  Please edit the question to be more specific about the behavior you're observing that's different than what you expect. There should be enough information in the question that anyone can reproduce the issue.